# How to make CloudRun grpc node.js service accessible from internet i.e accept request and returns response?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-run, grpc-node

I have a Node.js gRPC service deployed on CloudRun, with the following configurations:

1. Continuous integration from Github with Dockerfile with which it creates docker container.
2. I have exposed port 8080 in the container, it's the same port configured on CloudRun to run the service.
3. I have allowed `Allow direct access to your service from the internet` so it can accept all requests
4. In addition to all that I added HTTP/2 in network

The server is deployed well and works fine, I see the logs, and when I make http call on 8080 port it logs, that server couldn't respond to Chrome, Postman etc.

The problem is whenever I make a gRPC call the url of this service from the internet I get this error:

[image: Error from Postman, gRPC Request]

Here is my server code snippet

```js
const { connect } = require("mongoose");
const { loadSync } = require("@grpc/proto-loader");
const { loadPackageDefinition, Server, ServerCredentials } = require("@grpc/grpc-js");

require('dotenv').config();

const sessionProto = './src/prototypes/session.proto';
const sessionService = require('./src/services/session');

const healthProto = './src/prototypes/health.proto';
const healthService = require('./src/services/health');

const protoLoaderOptions = {
    oneofs: true,
    longs: String,
    enums: String,
    keepCase: true,
    defaults: true,
};

const healthPackageDefinition = loadSync(healthProto, protoLoaderOptions);
const healthProtoDefinition = loadPackageDefinition(healthPackageDefinition);

const sessionPackageDefinition = loadSync(sessionProto, protoLoaderOptions);
const sessionProtoDefinition = loadPackageDefinition(sessionPackageDefinition);

const server = new Server();

// Services
server.addService(healthProtoDefinition.HealthService.service, healthService);
server.addService(sessionProtoDefinition.SessionService.service, sessionService);

server.bindAsync(
    `0.0.0.0:${process.env.PORT}`,
    ServerCredentials.createInsecure(),
    async (error, port) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error(error.message);
            process.exit();
        } else {
            try {
                await connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL);
                console.log(`Server running at http://0.0.0.0:${port}`);
                server.start();
            } catch (e) {
                console.error(e.message);
                process.exit();
            }
        }
    }
);
```

I searched all over the web, couldn't find the solution for this, I appreciate your help, thanks!

I tried all possible ports: 8080, 443 and 50051, couldn't get around it.

I expected it to return the response just fine as other tutorials show it, it seems straight foward and no one got this error before.

Thanks in advance for any help!